# Assignment of variable based on other column

Tags: r

Suppose I have this data.frame :

```
tdata <- structure(list(fyear = c("1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", 
"1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1972", 
"1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", 
"1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", 
"1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", 
"1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", 
"1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", 
"1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), .Names = "fyear")
```

And I want to assign a 1 to `tdata$check` if `fyear == 1975`.  I've tried this if statement, but it's throwing an error

```
if(tdata$fyear == 1975)) tdata$check <- 1
```

Error :

```
Warning message:
In if (ex$fyear == 1975) ex$check <- 1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Try `tdata$check <- (tdata$fyear==1975)+0L` or use the `mutate` from `dplyr` as this is already a `tbl_df`  If you need to use a conditional statement, `ifelse` would be better suitable here as it is vectorized ie. `mutate(tdata, check= ifelse(fyear==1975, 1, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean approach above is clever, but to assign any value:

```
tdata$check[tdata$fyear==1975] <- 1
```

If you want 0s instead of NAs

```
tdata$check <- 0
tdata$check[tdata$fyear==1975] <- 1
```

Comment: This worked best...and also worked with a larger issue I was having.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
tdata$check <- (tdata$fyear==1975)*1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
tdata$check[tdata$fyear==1975]<-1
```

which produces a column of 1 (if true) or NA if not true.